# Why ContentPresenter's render time is bigger than its children's sum?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, contentpresenter

See the below picture:

[image: ContentPresenter's render time is bigger than others]

I just used Performance Profiler in VS2017 and i found that the listBoxItem's ContentPresenter render time is so bigger than its children's.

I have to reduce total render time (which is 1.1s roughly).
Sum of ListBoxItems render time is also 1.1s.

I don't know why time difference is made.

The Listbox's visual tree is like this:

- ListBox(3057)

  - Border(3056)

    - ScollViewer(3055)

      - Grid(3054)

        - ScrollContentPresenter(3031)

          - ItemsPresenter(3029)

            - VirtualizingStackPanel(3028)

              - ListBoxItem(120)
              - ListBoxItem(84) ...

Comment: Obviously the `ContentPresenter` is not finished when its children are finished. E.g., handling the templating also adds extra time. To reduce the rendering time of an item container you must reduce the complexity of its tree i.e. `DataTemplate`. The tree of the `ListBox` has no weight. So it would be more interesting to see the tree of `ListBoxItem` instead.

Comment: _"(total render time is 1.1s roughly). Sum of ListBoxItems render time is also 1.1s."_ Looks roughly equal to me.

Comment: @BionicCode thanks to reply. my boss want faster ui.... but i don't know how do i..

Comment: As I wrote before, you need to optimize your `DataTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` content. Also make sure that UI virtualization is not disabled! In case of tzhe `ListBox` it is enabled by default. You can test this by checking the count of the `ListBox.Items` collection in debugging mode. If you need more help please post the `ListBox´ and the `DataTemplate`, `ItemContainerStyle` and all the logic you may have implemented to execute on item loaded or rendering. If elements of the `DataTemplate` are also styled and templated, then it's worth to inspect them too.

Comment: The goal is to remove redundant element attributes, triggers and to reduce the element depth of the visual tree to improve rendering time. Optimizing data binding modes e.g., by setting `Binding.Mode` to `OneTime` where possible also helps a lot. Usually `ListBox` is  quite fast. Maybe you also want/need to improve the data generation time (when populating the source collection) if possible e.g. optimize iterations and LINQ expresions.

Comment: It's difficult to help if all you show is an image of your profiler results.

Comment: How many items are you showing? To test if UI virtualization is enabled load e.g. 1,000 items into the `ListBox`. Then use a visual tree viewer (Visual Studio or Snoop) to assert that only a few e.g., 30 items (and not all) are actually loaded in the `VirtualizingStackPanel` of the  `ListBox`.

Comment: @BionicCode first. i show the 30 items but in visual tree i can see 3057 element.... now i will turn off the virtualizingStackPanel option! thank!

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understood you correctly. Don't turn virtualization off. When you inspect the visual tree you must check the `ListBoxItem` count. The count must be less than the total item ccount in the `ItemsSource`. When virtualization is enabled only the visible items are rendered. This will improve rendering time.

Comment: oh. dear. now i understand yours. just simplify the visual tree. unify panels, remove trigger, reduce converter. right? i think these are not easy... all of my controls have (VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling") virtuallizing code.
Thanks for your kind answer @BionicCode

Answer (score 0):

I can reduce visual tree's Control.

The way that i do is "redefine some Control's ControlTemplate"

Before redefine ControlTemplate, my ListBoxItem have Bd(Border), ContentPresenter, Grid,, etc. like below
[image: Visual Tree]

After redefine ControlTemplate like below xaml

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                         <ContentPresenter.Style>
                             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                                 <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
                                 <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
                              </Style>
                          </ContentPresenter.Style>
                      </ContentPresenter>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then i can remove "Bd"(Border) like below.

- ListBoxItem

  - ContentPresenter

    - Grid ...

To reduce render time, I will find useless Controls and remove.